# Matlab find index of matched elements and replace values

Tags: matlab, indexing, comparison, matching

I want to create an array of indices using Matlab's `find`-function. Here is what I need to do:

I have an array `a1` containing time data in the `datenum` format (incomplete set) and an array `v1` (same length as `a1`) containing some values.

I now created a new array `a2` also containing time data in the datenum format (this time complete set, hence `length(a2) > length(a1)`) and initialized an array `v2` with zeros with `length(a2)`.

What I want to do is to replace the zeros in `v2` with the data in `v1` where `a1` matches `a2`.

I think this is a case for indexing, where I ultimately want to do the following:

```
v2(ind) = v1; % whereas ind contains the indices of the matched elements of a1 and a2
```

However when I try to create an array `ind` to store the indices where a1 matches `a2` I get an error related to the dimensions:

```
ind = find(a1==a2);
```

Error: `Matrix dimensions must agree`

Starting point:

```
a1 = [2;3;4;6;9]; % simplified time-vector ("incomplete")
v1 = [1;2;1;1;2]; % data for each time-point in a1
a2 = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10]; % "complete" time-vector
v2 = zeros(length(a2),1); % initialize final output variable
```

Desired Outcome:

```
v2 = [0;1;2;1;0;6;0;0;2;0] % values of v1 inserted where a1 matches a2
```

Can someone help me out here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your problem statement.  Would it be possible to provide a short example and expected output?

Comment: Try `ismember` instead of `==`.

Comment: Added an simplified example and the desired output. Hopefully this helps in understanding my problem. 'ismember' didn't work for when I tried it...

Comment: `ismember` worked! Only difference was that I had to use `[ind1, ind2] = ismember(a1,a2,'rows')`, whereas ìnd2` then provides the indices I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As posted above in the comment, `ismember` worked when used as follows to retrieve the indices where `a1` matches `a2`:

```
[ind1, ind2] = ismember(a1,a2,'rows');
```

ind2 contains then contains the indicies, which I used as follows:

```
v2(ind2) = v1;
```